# Configuring remote Gradle Build Cache on build server

Tags: gradle

Is it possible to configure a [Gradle remote cache](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html#sec:build_cache_configure_remote) from the command line or on the daemon?

Ideally I'd like to configure our build server to use a remote cache without requiring all users of my build server to update all of their settings.gradle files.

I could also inject the required lines into the settings file if it doesn't exist potentially. I can't find any documentation so that leads me to believe this could be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely you'd do this with an init script, specified on the gradle command line with `--init-script`

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html